# What is the visitors' HTTP User Agent stored in log_visitor_info used for?

Tags: database, log, logging

I was wondering, where in Magento the visitors' HTTP User Agent Information is used. The `log_visitor_info` table is pretty big (and for me it seems the user agent information is useless?).

I grepped through the code and all I found were the following three usages:

- Check for ignored user agents (anyway, not the stored user agent data but the one received from the helper) (see `Mage_Log_Model_Visitor`, `_construct()`)
- Adding the user agent information in (`Mage_Log_Model_Visitor`, `initServerData()`)
- Saving the visitor information (`Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor`, `_saveVisitorInfo()`)

Is there any other place (Reports, Menu item in the backend,...) where the HTTP user agent information is shown/needed?

Comment: I cannot see any other uses for it. It could be useful but I cannot see a current use.

Comment: I thought the design exceptions in admin used this to match certain themes/packages/etc based on a user agent, but maybe I'm wrong, I'll have to look it up.

Comment: I would find it immensely useful to put on order receipts, as when a customer claims there is an error in the store it helps tremendously to know their OS/browser combination for troubleshooting/trying to replicate that. 

I've posted a question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73956/how-can-i-show-customer-os-and-browser-user-agent-on-order-slip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly I cannot see anything that directly uses the user agent stored against the visitor log entry.

The package theme exceptions directly use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` value as with the other places that check user agent.

My best guess, and sorry that it is a guess, is that someone thought that maybe it might be useful to store this information. A shop owner may want to see how many visitors are using which browser, but I cannot see currently anything that does this.

Comment: Thanks for checking. It would make sense to use/view the data if it's stored (and not just filling up the database, if log is enabled).