# How can I show customer OS and browser (User agent) on order slip?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

For troubleshooting reasons, I would like to be able to see  what browser and OS the customer used to place their order, ideally right on their order in Magento backend. How would that best be done?

Magento version 1.8.10. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where to start, so I haven't tried anything. I'm wondering how to go about it, as in how to fetch that data and how to make it appear on the order.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the information at the order

   [Create a new row on the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento)
2. Show it on the order page

   Edit the template which the Template hints tell you, I recommend to [create your own admin theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14111/custom-package-theme-for-admin-module-that-falls-back-to-default-package) and output the `$order->getYourAttribute()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm wondering _how_ to save that info at the order, and _how_ to display show it on the order page.

Comment: updated the answer.